# How to parse this type of string using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

Hey guys i want to parse this type of string:

```
    {"1":
    [
        {"OrderItemId":832,"ItemId":995,"Price":0},
        {"OrderItemId":833,"ItemId":997,"Price":0},
        {"OrderItemId":834,"ItemId":999,"Price":0}
    ],
    "2":
    [
        {"OrderItemId":835,"ItemId":1008,"Price":0},
        {"OrderItemId":836,"ItemId":1057,"Price":0}
    ]
}
```

its very important for me, so please guys help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this, if you want to access the OrderItemId

```
var test =  {"1":
    [
        {"OrderItemId":832,"ItemId":995,"Price":0},
        {"OrderItemId":833,"ItemId":997,"Price":0},
        {"OrderItemId":834,"ItemId":999,"Price":0}
    ],
    "2":
    [
        {"OrderItemId":835,"ItemId":1008,"Price":0},
        {"OrderItemId":836,"ItemId":1057,"Price":0}
    ]
}

alert(test["1"][0]['OrderItemId']);
alert(test["1"][1]['OrderItemId']);
alert(test["1"][2]['OrderItemId']);

alert(test["2"][0]['OrderItemId']);
alert(test["2"][1]['OrderItemId']);
```

UPDATE, to iterate trough test with unknown lengths

```
for (var i=0;i<test["1"].length;i++) {
    alert(test["1"][i]['OrderItemId']);
}
```

Here with full automatic enumaration

```
var number, count = 0;
var en = [];
for(number in test) {
    en[count]=number;
    count++;
}
for (var r=0;r<en.length;r++) {
    alert(en[r]);
    for (var i=0;i<test[en[r]].length;i++) {
        alert(test[en[r]][i]['OrderItemId']);
    }
}
```

Comment: cool. but how can i do it when i don't know the the length? i mean to say that, how can i do it dynamically..?

Comment: still i have to give test["1"] as static. i don't want to give "1" as static. i want to parse it for any number of array..

Comment: Hey i am not fully satisfied.Please give me solution so that i can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: have made yet another update, last one - it should be clear now :-)

Comment: got the exact answer what i want. thanx a ton. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Use [this](http://www.json.org/js.html) to parse it. (or any other library you preffer, maybe jQuery)

Comment: +1 for concisitude. You might want to give a JSON.parse code sample.

Answer (score 2):

//You can do by this way also :

```
<script>
    var employees = { "accounting" : [   // accounting is an array in employees.
                                    { "firstName" : "John",  // First element
                                      "lastName"  : "Doe",
                                      "age"       : 23 },

                                    { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                      "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                      "age"       : 32 }
                                  ], // End "accounting" array.                                  
                  "sales"       : [ // Sales is another array in employees.
                                    { "firstName" : "Sally", // First Element
                                      "lastName"  : "Green",
                                      "age"       : 27 },

                                    { "firstName" : "Jim",   // Second Element
                                      "lastName"  : "Galley",
                                      "age"       : 41 }
                                  ] // End "sales" Array.
                } // End Employees


    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in employees.accounting) {
        output+="<li>" + employees.accounting[i].firstName + " " + employees.accounting[i].lastName + "--" + employees.accounting[i].age+"</li>";
    }
    output+="</ul>";

    var output1="<ul>";
    for (var j in employees.sales) {
        output1+="<li>" + employees.sales[j].firstName + " " + employees.sales[j].lastName + "--" + employees.sales[j].age+"</li>";
    }
    output+="</ul>";

    alert(output1);

</script>
```

Comment: i want that parsing takes "sales" or "accounting" itself. any idea..?

Comment: coz its possible that may be hundreds of names like "sales" and "accounting". what to do..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might have been due to line ending.

Here is a working[tested in chrome dev console] code:

```
var jsonStr = '{"1":\
    [\
        {"OrderItemId":832,"ItemId":995,"Price":0},\
        {"OrderItemId":833,"ItemId":997,"Price":0},\
        {"OrderItemId":834,"ItemId":999,"Price":0}\
    ],\
    "2":\
    [\
        {"OrderItemId":835,"ItemId":1008,"Price":0},\
        {"OrderItemId":836,"ItemId":1057,"Price":0}\
    ]\
}';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr); // works!
```

Comment: i have applied "\" for line ending.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery to Parse JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Also have a look at this SO question [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add backward slashes after ending if every object item. You can separate with comma only.